# Ethereum donation appraisal?

Tags: united-states, charitable-contributions, cryptocurrency

I donated some Ethereum to a Fidelity donor-advised fund this year. The amount was worth over $5k, which I believe means it falls under the IRS's appraisal requirement.

How can I find a "qualified" appraiser to do this? Ideally one who wouldn't charge too much, since honestly this won't be much work! (Look up the price at the time of the donation and write it down.)

Comment: Did you actually donate Ethereum? In most cases, respectable institutions consider cryptocurrency as a payment method, not a currency, and they cash it out immediately and consider the donation as the sale amount in USD.

Comment: @cHao Fidelity appears to accept cryptocurrency donations. https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/06/business/bitcoin-charity-donations.html

Comment: "As a result, “it may be difficult to find a qualified appraiser” with the requisite education and experience. For this reason, it may be wise for potential donors to limit their total contributions to all charities in virtual currency form to less than $5,000." http://www.pgdc.com/pgdc/charitable-gifts-bitcoin-tax-appraisal-legal-and-processing-considerations

Comment: @ceejayoz: Fidelity apparently does cash out immediately, though. ("The fund uses Coinbase, a digital asset exchange company, to accept donations and convert them into dollars as soon as they come in.") If the price comes almost directly from the market, is an appraiser still needed?

Comment: @cHao It's an interesting question. I'd bet you could get away with reporting it to the IRS as a cash donation based on the ETH price at the time of the donation, but I'm not a CPA. OP would have a much easier time if they'd just sold the ETH, then donated the USD proceeds.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Much easier, yes. But they'd also pay capital gains tax on any profit from the sale. (The alleged benefit of donating assets rather than cash is that since charities don't have to pay taxes, they can sell the ETH without taking that hit.)

Comment: @cHao Ah, that's a very, very good point.

Comment: exactly, the whole point of donating the Ethereum was to save on capital gains tax.

Comment: Btw, I think I've found an appraiser. They're going to charge me $600. Not sure if I should answer my own question with specific details about who I found, or something more generic, or leave it unanswered.

Claiming it as a cash donation is interesting. I've heard if you explain your reasoning clearly, the IRS doesn't get too mad even about silly screwups. So I dunno, it might be worth a try.

Comment: @cHao, I'm curious why you say 'alleged' benefit? just b/c you're skeptical it's worth the hassle?

Comment: @DavidC: Basically. If you have to find and hire an appraiser, there's that annoyance...plus, their fee will come out of either the donation amount, or your pocket. So the benefit isn't as great as advertised.

Comment: You guys are missing the point of donating an appreciated asset.  You donate the asset not the cash because then YOU don't realize a taxable gain and the charity gets the full value of the asset.  I'm sure it won't cost 15% of $5,000 for the charity to figure out how to sell a couple ETH.

Comment: @quid: Problem is, if the cost of an appraiser equals or exceeds the tax you avoided, you're being screwed over -- the donee receives a bigger donation than you budgeted for (because you can't subtract the appraiser's fees from the donation, unless the appraiser takes payment in ETH), and the appraiser gets the money you would have given Uncle Sam if you'd sold the asset yourself.

Comment: @cHao, screwed over for donating is an interesting way to think about it....  I'd avoid charity if your only purpose is a personal benefit.

Comment: @quid: It's not about personal benefit, it's about avoiding personal hardship while giving. I find that a perfectly reasonable goal -- and frankly, i find guilting or conning people out of that goal to be unethical. Hence "screwed over". If i have $5k to spare, that is not $5600. If giving $5k ends up costing me $5600, then i can't afford to give $5k. But the whole reason this post exists is because someone gave $5k without knowing an appraiser was going to charge an extra $600 later.

Comment: To clarify a few things:

(1) $5k is mentioned in my question as the limit that triggers the need for an appraiser, not the donation amount (which is larger).

(2) I agree this would be silly if it were only a $5000 donation. Then the 15% cap gains tax saved would only be $750, pretty close to what the appraiser charges.

(3) "... someone gave $5k without knowing an appraiser was going to charge..." -- this isn't true -- I did know I would be charged (roughly) that amount when I made the donation. This question exists because at the time I just didn't know where to find someone for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only appraisers I've been able to find that in this space are [Charitable Solutions](http://charitablesolutionsllc.com/virtual-currency-appraisals/) and [Crypto Appraisers](https://cryptoappraisers.com/). They do qualified appraisals of Bitcoin and other common cryptocurrencies in addition to Ethereum.

You could try searching around for an appraiser at any of the [major](http://www.appraisers.org/find-an-appraiser) [appraiser](https://www.appraisersassociation.org/index.cfm?&pageID=741)
[associations](https://www.naifa.com/search/all.asp), but there don't seem to be any results for cryptocurrencies (as of date) so you'd have to start asking general property or business appraisers if they'd be interested in branching out a bit. Also, in my experience most of the time the fees will be in the upper hundreds, if not over a thousand, for even the most basic appraisal.

Still, given that Ethereum is up around 900% over the last year, the tax savings could be significant (thousands of dollars).
Probably well worth several hundred bucks and a little hassle.